# jQuery SlideUp and SlideDown functionality swapped/interchanged?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very basic jQuery code that slides up a div on page load. What I don't understand, is that it slides down after clicking a div with "close" class, even if the function is slideup on click as you can see below. If you read the code, it simply shows that it should slidedown on page load, then slide up after clicking the button with close class. But what it does is slideup on page load, and slidedown on click of the close button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('#announcement').delay(2000).slideDown();

    jQuery('.close').click(function () {
        jQuery('#announcement').slideUp();
    }); 
});
```

I wonder why it doesn't work if I put slidedown inside the function, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('#announcement').delay(2000).slideUp();

    jQuery('.close').click(function () {
        jQuery('#announcement').slideDown();
    }); 
});
```

But it works as expected if I put the slideup within the function, and slidedown outside the function.

The logic doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  Your question would greatly benefit from having a snippet (edit then click `[<>]`) that *demonstrates* the problem as it's currently unclear which code you are using and which does/doesn't work (*"it works as expected"*).

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it.